# Class java.nio.file.Files throws FileAlreadyExistsException as "optional specific exception". What does it mean?

Tags: java, jvm, nio

Does anybody know, what exactly "optional specific exception" means?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Some JVMs throw it and some not? If they don't do it, throw they a general IOException or no exception at all? It there a statistic over different implementations, how "optional" it really is?

Comment: I think it is optional because there are situations where the existence of the file should not cause an `Exception`. The JavaDocs say *FileAlreadyExistsException - if a file of that name already exists and the CREATE_NEW option is specified (optional specific exception)*, that means it is only thrown if you use the option `CREATE_NEW` and the file already exists. If you use `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, then this `FileAlreadyExistsException` would keep your program from working correctly.

Comment: Look for the "Optional Specific Exceptions" section in the java.nio.file package description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the book "Java I/O, NIO and NIO.2" by Jeff Friesen:

> `FileAlreadyExistsException` is an example of an optional specific
>   exception. It's optional because it's thrown when the underlying
>   operating system can detect the specific error leading to the exception.
>   If the error cannot be detected, its `IOException` ancestor is thrown instead.

Comment: so the optionality is about the specificity of the type of Exception, not about the occurrence of an Exception. It is an **optionally specific** exception. Technically both `optional specific exception` and `optionally specific exception` are correct, but the latter description is less ambiguous.